# Replace 'Enter' symbol to a blank space in MS Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I want to record a macro such that it will replace all 'line break' symbol after the current cursor position to a blank space.
For example if the text is:
*My name is Sumit. I

love

Stackoverflow*

Now if the cursor is just next to 'love' and I press the macro button it should come like this:

*My name is Sumit. I

 love Stackoverflow*

I searched internet and wrote this (but this is not working)

```
Sub Replace()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you'd want to change

```
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
```

to

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

and

```
.MatchWildcards = True
```

to

```
.MatchWildcards = False
```

The first change should prevent the search from going back around and replacing content before the cursor and the second change turns off Wildcards (^p is not a wildcard character).

But it might help to know exactly how it's not working, if those changes aren't sufficient.